# onChange event is not working in color type input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I search a lot and find answers on Stack Overflow but all in vain, nothing is working for me. I want to get the color value when color is changed in `input` field.

Here is my code, please check this why it's not working.

```
 <input type="color" id="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" onchange="test()" />
```

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
 function test(){
    console.log('working.....'); 
 }
```

This function is not working, if you replace `onChange` with `onclick` it's working fine, but why not for `onChange`?

Comment: Just write the code where you are changing the color. I don't think there is a color change event though.

Comment: Is it similar to a select input where change is only triggered when it loses focus?

Comment: Try with onblur event, <input type="text" onblur="myFunction()">

Comment: It's working fine. what error are you getting ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I get the same behavior both with Chrome and Firefox on Windows and it only occurs with pure black, pure white, o any color very close to either one of them.

If you look at the Color picker you'll notice that the rgb values don't change when you move the cursor in the main square (they do if you use the vertical slider to the right, but that's not what the average user would tend to do).

[image]

The same behavior occurs with other applications using the same color picker, for instance MSpaint or Tkinter's `tkColorChooser.askcolor()`. I assume this is Window's default color picker since "color" has the British English spelling "colour", that's my default language choice.

To fix this, just use any color that's not `#ffffff` or `#000000` (or close) as your start color.

```html
<label for="doesntWork1">doesn't work</label> <input type="color" id="doesntWork1" value="#ffffff" onchange="alert(this.value);" />
<p>
<label for="doesntWork2">doesn't work</label> <input type="color" id="doesntWork2" value="#000000" onchange="alert(this.value);" />
<p>
<label for="works1">works</label> <input type="color" id="works1" value="#fdffff" onchange="alert(this.value);" />
<p>
<label for="works2">works</label> <input type="color" id="works2" value="#000002" onchange="alert(this.value);" />
```

Comment: Even those inputs with notWorking are working in the snippet test!

Comment: In Firefox on macos (Big Sur) those do pull up a colour picker, but I also find that the browser is losing track of what picker affects what input. Try and open an input, change the colour, and then before closing the input double click on a different input and try changing those colours too. The reference to the current swatch seems to get confused.

Comment: @danjah I am experiencing the same behavior. Do you know of a work around for it?

Answer (score 24):

This problem some people are having with inconsistent behaviour in different browsers happens because you're using the `onchange` event (`change` in jQuery), which is **not** the appropriate event for color inputs (that's why it sometimes works and it sometimes doesn't, especially on Mac OS X).

You should use `oninput` (or `input` when using jQuery), which works fine in all browsers and platforms.

```
$('#bgcolor').on('input',
    function() {
        console.log($(this).val());
    }
);
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. `onchange` is not the correct event handler for an HTML5 color picker. Instead, it's `oninput`. Works even in Vanilla JS.

Comment: you are a saviour !! Thanks

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Access the value like this.

```js
function test(t) {
  console.log(t.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="color" id="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" onchange="test(this)" onkeyup="test(this)" />
```

Comment: It's working fine for me. Which version and browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using chrome 52. Is there any problem in chrome version

Comment: 52.0.2743.116 (Official Build) m (32-bit)

Comment: @PunitGajjar : Browser's like IE haven't implemented color picker yet!

Comment: @Pugazh To support IE, making it call on keyup for all browsers. I don't find it suitable.

Comment: @LaraBelle didn't work for me either so I did some further investigation,  check [my (accepted) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47471487/2314737).

Comment: may be try t.target.value

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps you .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="color" id="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
    </body>
    <script>
        $(document).on("change" , "#bgcolor" , function(){
            alert($(this).val());
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

```js
$(document).on("change" , "#bgcolor" , function(){
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <input type="color" id="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
```

Comment: @AzeemHaider checked it right now.  Please select any color and it will show you color code you have selected in alert. Its working buddy.  i wonder if you are telling  by seeing this {
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
}  Ignore it .

Comment: No nothing is showing this is not working I'm using chrome 52.0.2743.116 (Official Build) m (32-bit)

Comment: @AzeemHaider , make sure you have added the jquery ,Also let me know what error you are getting on console.

Comment: This is not working in chrome. I tried it on mozilla and it runs well. But please do include browser compatibility. Thanks! Upvote!

Comment: let me include my HTML in  my answer,

Comment: No error is shown even no color is select. I also checked it on stackoverflow but its not working even stackoverflow

Comment: @AzeemHaider i am using Chrom Version 52.0.2743.116 m (64-bit)

Comment: is there any problem in browser. which browser you are using

Comment: @PunitGajjar this is not working I checked it in firefox

Comment: @AzeemHaider , i have checked in Firefox 48.0 , its working smoothly .

Comment: Please _explain_ your answers. Don't just code dump. Why did the OP's original solution not work?

Comment: @AzeemHaider: Works for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Try following snippet with JavaScript and JQuery.

```js
//Javascript function
function test(t) {
  console.log(t.value);
}
//Jquery function
$('#bgcolor').change(function(){
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="color" id="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" onchange="test(this)" />
```

Comment: That nick is evil!

Answer (score 1):

its working for me, check it below

```js
function hello()
{
 alert("hi");
}
```

```html
<input type="color" value="#ff0000" onchange="hello();">
```

Answer (score 1):

On my angular (13) project, I used `(input)=""` :

```
<input
    (input)="someFunction()"
    type="color" />
```

This continuously triggers the function `someFunction()` on realtime while picking color from the gradient.

Answer (score 0):

```
"Instead of onchange on input type color use the input event in JavaScript.
Here is the working code."

<input type="color" id="colorPicker" value="#333" style="width:100%;height:210px;      border:none;background:none">

<script>
       colorpicker = document.getElementById('colorPicker');
       colorpicker.addEventListener('input', ()=>{
            console.log('my color is: ',colorpicker.value);
       });
        
</script>
```