# Update color while drag on color panel

Tags: javascript, html

I used all the events from JavaScript to get the color code while drag on color panel. All methods are working fine for certain mouse events. Can anyone guide me to get the color on drag?

```js
function fillElements(ev) {
    color = ev.target.value
    console.log(color);
}
```

```html
<input onchange="fillElements(event)" type="color" value="#3367d6">
```

Comment: Didn't Get Your Question

Comment: Please run the code snippet. Click on the color input field. Drag on the panel to change the color. fillElements() function need to be called on drag instead of onchange.

Comment: You can check [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39264722/onchange-event-is-not-working-in-color-type-input)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, and you want `fillElements` to be called on drag event inside color selection box, you can use `oninput` instead of `onchange` inside `<input>`.

```js
function fillElements(ev) {
    color = ev.target.value
    console.log(color);
}
```

```html
<input oninput="fillElements(event)" type="color" value="#3367d6">
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. This is what I expected. I don't know how do I missed this event